# sql query in wpf c# not working | error in set result sqlquery in "var" variable

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, variables

i want to get max code(my means last id of columns) with sql query

Thats my code :

```
var qre = dbms.Database.SqlQuery<TCOD_BANKS>("SELECT MAX(CODE) FROM TCOD_BANKS");
var data_main11 = qre.ToList();
foreach (var x1 in qre)
{
    var aasd = x1.CODE;
}
```

When i start my code I see this error

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'DENAF1399Model.TCOD_BANKS'. A member of the type, 'CODE', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'
```

---

my table is : TCOD_BANKS
my column id is : CODE as int

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query `SELECT MAX(CODE) FROM TCOD_BANKS` will return a single number, so you can't try to read a result set with items of type `TCOD_BANKS`. Try reading a single number from the result like this:

```
var qre = dbms.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT MAX(CODE) FROM TCOD_BANKS").First();
```